# Should i change my MySQL database structure.

Tags: mysql

This is my current Mysql structure.

2 Tables:

```
1.) Movies
2.) Genres
```

Both tables are connected by a column named `movie_id`.

Here is an example of my table structure:

---

**Table**: `Movies`

```
movie_id          movie_name

1                 Superman
2                 Logan
3                 The Hangover
4                 8 Mile
5                 The Dark Knight
```

**Table** Genres

```
movie_id          genres_name
1                 Science Fiction
1                 Action
1                 Fantasy
1                 Adventure

2                 Action
2                 Drama
2                 Science Fiction

3                 Comedy

4                 Music
4                 Drama

5                 Crime
5                 Thriller
5                 Action
5                 Drama
```

---

---

Now many people recommended my to change my table structure to this one:

**Table**: Movies

```
movie_id          movie_name

1                 Superman
2                 Logan
3                 The Hangover
4                 8 Mile
5                 The Dark Knight
```

**Table:** Genres_id

```
genres_id          genres_name
1                  Science Fiction
2                  Action
3                  Fantasy
4                  Adventure
5                  Drama
6                  Comedy
7                  Music
8                  Thriller  
9                  Crime
```

**Table** Genres

```
movie_id          genres_id
1                 1
1                 2
1                 3
1                 4

2                 2
2                 5
2                 1

3                 6

4                 7
4                 5

5                 9
5                 8
5                 2
5                 5
```

I am currently using the 1st database structure. But should I change it to the second one? But what will be the advantages? Better speed? (I really need it)

Let me know, if you need more information, thanks.

Comment: That's many to many relationship so it's better to have bridge table in case you want to perform queries for more than 1 genres.

Comment: I can already do that @digit

Comment: For me second one is the better choice.

Comment: I Already know, everyone say, 2nd is better. I wanna know why?

Comment: You must do the second DB structure for many to many relationship. Because in the first DB structure, There is repeated value of genres_name in Genres table. You can read the database normalization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second database structure has the following advantages:

- By implementing referential integrity it will be impossible to assign an invalid genre to a movie. In the first option spelling mistakes could be made (e.g. `Sience Fiction`). To avoid that from happening in the first option, one could add a database constraint to only allow certain values, but listing those would get very close to actually creating the third table for it, and allowing for a new genre later on would require a DML statement (instead of a simple `insert` in the second option).
- When the movies data is limited, and there are still genres for which no movie record has been inserted, there is no easy way for the user to know which genres are available, since they just are not stored. In the first option they could be present as constraint values, but there is no SQL standard to retrieve those from the database dictionary. In practice you would just duplicate this knowledge in the application language, and define a closed array of possible values there. But that would be just transferring the data responsibility away from the database.
- It takes less space. Numerical foreign key values take less space than a genre text string. Admittedly, these strings will still be stored in a (separate) table, but only once per genre. As the movies and related moviegenres table would typically have more records than the number of different possible genres, there is a space gain. The same holds true for the index one would like to create on the genres, so a query to list movies of a certain genre would run efficiently. An index on numbers will take less space than an index on text strings.
- The query to list all genres will run more efficiently. This is a common use-case, for instance when you need to populate a drop-down listbox for the user to select a genre.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect this:

```
CREATE TABLE Movies (
    movie_id  INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    movie_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY ix_movie_name (movie_name));

CREATE TABLE Genres (
    genre_id  INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    genre_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL.
    UNIQUE KEY ix_genre_name (genre_name));

CREATE TABLE Movie_Genres (
    movie_id  INT NOT NULL,
    genre_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, genre_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES Movies(movie_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES Genres(genre_id))
);
```

A search on name by genre finds just one genre record by an index.

Also the genres for a movie are retrieved in a direct way.